# Why is awk sub not replacing my input

Tags: bash, awk

I have been struggling to write an awk program that would take input files and display the original and space separated filename only in second column. Why is the following command not working for that?

`echo -e "abc/123\ndef/456" | awk '{l=$1; sub("./*", "", l); print "mv " $1, $l}'`

For the record, the above outputs

```
mv abc/123 abc/123
mv def/456 def/456
```

Comment: bash is capable of doing that on its own; why do you need awk?

Comment: Tunnel vision, I will update with the bash solution, thanks!

Comment: What output are you hoping to achieve? That sub() function will remove the first character of the string. Did you mean to use the regex `.*/` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`l` is the variable that holds the replaced text. `$l` is the value of the **column number** referenced by the value stored in the variable `l`. Since the `l` value does not start with digits, awk treats the string as the number "0", so you get `$0` which is the current record.

You want this instead

```
print "mv", $1, l
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for! For those interested, here is the command you can use to grab all files of the same name and store them somewhere
`find . -name "debug.log" | awk '{l=$1; b=$l; sub(".*/", "", b); print "mv " $1, b "-" NR}'`

Comment: Or maybe `mv -b -t . **/debug.log` (untested)

Comment: Wasn't aware of that, thanks again for sharing. Unfortunately it won't work as it complains about the files having the same name, but it is worth remembering either way. Also since I'm in bash the `**` expansion doesn't work, but would likely work in zsh for anyone reading

Comment: `shopt -s globstar` enables **